# HTML Grid Layout Inquiry

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

Hey fellow stack overflowers!

I had a question about utilizing CSS Grid Layout. Is there anything specific I need to include or reference in my HTML/CSS to be able to begin utilize the grid layout properties in my code? Or is it as simple as just giving my container div element a "display: grid" property and then I can use the grid layout properties in all the child elements within my container?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: see http://gridbyexample.com/browsers/ enable your browsers if not yet , then https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ will be usefull too

Comment: thanks @GCyrillus the css-tricks guide is very helpful I'm starting to slightly get the hang of the grid layout.